# ''I can pick you up on the street''?

Tags: prepositions

I know that we can say:
'I can pick you up from the station'

Can I say like this (see below) if I mean the following: 'I want you to wait me on the sidewalk of the street'.

'I can pick you up on/in the street'?

Comment: I wouldn't, as a man, tell a woman "I can pick you up on the street".  It's has the wrong connotation.

Comment: It would not be that vague either. It would be, say, "I'll pick you up outside your house" or "I want you to wait on the corner by Vane's Cafe where I can pull over."

Answer (score 1):

"The street" is not a clear place.  There are lots of streets, which one do you mean?

You'd say  "I can pick you up at the corner of Main street and Park Avenue" (for example) or "... from the road outside your house".

In comments, people have hinted that "pick up on the street" has the wrong connotation.  To be explicit, this phrase is used to mean "hire a prostitute".

Answer (score 0):

"I can pick you up in the street." is not a phrase we use in English.

"I can pick you up on the street." also sounds a bit awkward. I think what you want to say is "I can pick you up from the sidewalk."

Comment: Note that _sidewalk_ is not used in the UK although the OP did not specify where they were.